# Construct a tree from a list with levels

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

I have some data(Python `list` of `dict`s) which looks like:

```
[
    {'value': 'A', 'level': 0},
    {'value': 'B', 'level': 1},
    {'value': 'C', 'level': 2},
    {'value': 'D', 'level': 1},
    {'value': 'E', 'level': 2},
    {'value': 'F', 'level': 2},
    {'value': 'G', 'level': 0},
    {'value': 'H', 'level': 1},
    ...
]
```

It represents a tree, which looks like:

```
<root>
|
+---A
|   |
|   +---B
|   |   |
|   |   +---C
|   |
|   +---D
|       |
|       +---E
|       |
|       +---F
+---G
    |
    +---H
```

And here's **what I want**: Efficient, elegant(Pythonic?) way to construct a tree from the array which has levels(in other words, depths) only.

So that I could access to the tree:

```
root = build_tree(data) # or somewhat proper arguments

print(root.children) # => [<Node A>, <Node G>]
print(root.children[0].children) # => [<Node B>, <Node D>]
print(root.children[0].children[1].children]) # => [<Node E>, <Node F>]
print(root.children[1].children) # => [Node G]
print(root.children[1].children[0].children) # => []
```

I struggled to make some recursive functions to achieve it, but suddenly my brain stopped working. I'm waiting for your help.

Thank you.

--- EDITED ---

Here's what I wrote:

```
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, value):
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []

        self.__dict__.update(**value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<TreeNode %s>' % self.value

def build_tree(list, parent, start_idx=0, depth=0):
    current = TreeNode(parent, list[start_idx])
    parent.children.append(current)

    for idx in xrange(start_idx + 1, len(list)):
        if list[idx]['level'] == current.level:
            build_tree(list, parent, idx)
        elif list[idx]['level'] == current.level + 1:
            build_tree(list, current, idx)
        elif list[idx]['level'] < current.level:
            break

def print_tree(root, depth=0):
    for child in root.children:
        print('  ' * depth + '%r' % child)
        print_tree(child, depth + 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [
        {'value': 'A', 'level': 0},
        {'value': 'B', 'level': 1},
        {'value': 'C', 'level': 2},
        {'value': 'D', 'level': 1},
        {'value': 'E', 'level': 2},
        {'value': 'F', 'level': 2},
        {'value': 'G', 'level': 0},
        {'value': 'H', 'level': 1},
    ]

    root = TreeNode(None, {'value': 'root'})
    build_tree(data, root)

    print_tree(root)
```

And it gives:

```
<TreeNode A>
  <TreeNode B>
    <TreeNode C>
    <TreeNode E>
    <TreeNode F>
    <TreeNode F>
  <TreeNode D>
    <TreeNode E>
    <TreeNode F>
    <TreeNode F>
  <TreeNode D>
    <TreeNode E>
    <TreeNode F>
    <TreeNode F>
  <TreeNode H>
<TreeNode G>
  <TreeNode H>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your work. SO isn't here to write your code for you.

Comment: @Soviut I've wrote some test codes but those didn't work and very ugly. Should I post those codes?

Comment: Yes, post your attempts so that we can give you help you correct your issues.

Comment: @Soviut I posted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code should be simple. Your scheme implies there is an order to the children, so I will use a `list`.

```
In [8]: class Node:
   ...:     def __init__(self, val=None):
   ...:         self.value = val
   ...:         self.children = []
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         return "<Node {}>".format(self.value)
   ...:
```

The algorithm is also simple. Start at the root. Iterate over the data. While you are less than `"level"` nodes deep, continue moving down the children going to the *last child appended* attempting to go down the last node in children. If attempting to index into the last child fails, then we know we are where we have to be (assuming the input is well behaved!) and we append a new node with the value `"value"`. If you don't fail and make it to `"level"`, append a new node with the value `"value"`. Return to the root and repeat while you are not done iterating over the data.

```
In [9]: root = Node()

In [10]: for record in data:
    ...:     last = root
    ...:     for _ in range(record['level']):
    ...:         last = last.children[-1]
    ...:     last.children.append(Node(record['value']))
    ...:
```

Now, to check out our tree:

```
In [12]: root.children
Out[12]: [<Node A>, <Node G>]

In [13]: root.children[0].children
Out[13]: [<Node B>, <Node D>]

In [14]: root.children[0].children[1].children
Out[14]: [<Node E>, <Node F>]

In [15]: root.children[1].children
Out[15]: [<Node H>]

In [16]: root.children[1].children[0].children
Out[16]: []
```

Using your handy `print_tree` function:

```
In [24]: def print_tree(root, depth=0):
    ...:     for child in root.children:
    ...:         print('  ' * depth + '%r' % child)
    ...:         print_tree(child, depth + 1)
    ...:

In [25]: print_tree(root)
<Node A>
  <Node B>
    <Node C>
  <Node D>
    <Node E>
    <Node F>
<Node G>
  <Node H>
```

Comment: @hallazzang As for your recursive solution, keep in mind that recursion acts like a loop, but you have a loop *and* recursion...  You only need one in this case! This is why your data seems to be doubling!

Comment: Ok, I found where the duplication occurs in my code and fixed it, but still yours is much simpler.. btw, `try ~ except` block in your code seems not throwing any exceptions since there will always be level-0 element in the data. Could you explain what 'a terminal node' means in your comment `# this should only occur at a terminal node!`?

Comment: @hallazzang you're correct regarding the try-except, I was not thinking straight.

Comment: Well, then the reduced code looks so cool. Thanks again. You saved hours of my lifes and lines of my code.