# python - constructing a nested dict from a list

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I'm parsing some crappy lists in python from an api anbd outputting into a nested json structure with a specific format to be consumed by a tonne of front-end services.

The below list is an example with each item being a file's full path.  I cannot modify this input as it comes from external service that walks through a database.  Directory items do not appear in this list, only files, directory the file is in is evident form the path, i.e in below no MIPK/DORAS files exist. Example below:

```
"/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/CM.toroidal",
"/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/CM.Supervoid",
"/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.forest",
"/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.benign",
"/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.dunes",
"/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.tangeant",
"/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.astral",
"/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.forking"
```

There was a previous function used that was incredibly slow however I'm currently parsing the list using the following code.  The output format is not the exact format I want.  I'm getting stuck on appending a node to the root.

In the below it takes a path, finds the nested directories and removes the rootpath that's present in every file then creates a node object which has the appropriate nested structure.

After this is added to prev_node, it then get's appended to a dictionary using the directory name as the key.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def main():
    # Initialise
    root_path    = '/generic_root'
    store        = '/site_store'
    file_list    = [
        "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/CM.toroidal",
        "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/CM.Supervoid",
        "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.forest",
        "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.benign",
        "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.dunes",
        "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.tangeant",
        "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.astral",
        "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.forking"
    ]
    # Call loop and display results
    viewstore_tree_map = create_dir_tree(file_list, root_path, store)
    logging.info('\n\tView store keys: %s\n\tKeys: %s\n\tDict of store: %s',
                 len(viewstore_tree_map.keys()), viewstore_tree_map.keys(),
                 viewstore_tree_map)


def joiner(delimiter, *args):
    '''
    Joins path strings correctly, unpack before passing args
    '''
    return delimiter.join(list(args))


def create_dir_tree(file_list, root_path, store):
    '''
    File_list [LIST][STR]
    root_path [STR]
    store [STR]
    Return [DICT]
    '''
    node_map = {}
    full_root = root_path+store
    for sub_path in file_list:
        parents = sub_path.replace(full_root, '').split('/')[1:-1]
        prev_node = None
        node = None
        node_path = full_root
        # create tree structure for directory nodes
        for parent in parents:
            node_path = joiner('/', node_path, parent)
            node_exists = 1
            if node_path not in node_map:
                node_exists = 0
                node_map[node_path] = {
                    'name': parent,
                    'data': [],
                    'type': 'dir',
                    'path': node_path,
                }
            node = node_map[node_path]
            # Handles appending previous dict to data field of new dict
            if prev_node and not node_exists:
                prev_node['data'].append(node)
            prev_node = node
            # logger.info(pprint.pprint(prev_node))

        if node:
            node['data'].append({
                'name': sub_path.rsplit('/')[-1],
                'type': 'file',
                'path': sub_path
            })
    return node_map
```

The below is the output from the above code.  Which is massive and will be a considerable memory problem as these list eventually grow in size.

```
node_map = {
    '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE': {
        'type': 'dir',
        'data': [{
            'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.tangeant',
            'type': 'file',
            'name': 'CM.tangeant'
        }, {
            'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.astral',
            'type': 'file',
            'name': 'CM.astral'
        }, {
            'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.forking',
            'type': 'file',
            'name': 'CM.forking'
        }],
        'name': 'CRUDE',
        'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE'
    },
    '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE': {
        'type': 'dir',
        'data': [{
            'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.forest',
            'type': 'file',
            'name': 'CM.forest'
        }, {
            'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.benign',
            'type': 'file',
            'name': 'CM.benign'
        }, {
            'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.dunes',
            'type': 'file',
            'name': 'CM.dunes'
        }],
        'name': 'CRUDE',
        'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE'
    },
    '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES': {
        'type': 'dir',
        'data': [{
            'type': 'dir',
            'data': [{
                'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.tangeant',
                'type': 'file',
                'name': 'CM.tangeant'
            }, {
                'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.astral',
                'type': 'file',
                'name': 'CM.astral'
            }, {
                'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.forking',
                'type': 'file',
                'name': 'CM.forking'
            }],
            'name': 'CRUDE',
            'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE'
        }],
        'name': 'COMMODITIES',
        'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES'
    },
    '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK': {
        'type': 'dir',
        'data': [{
            'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/CM.toroidal',
            'type': 'file',
            'name': 'CM.toroidal'
        }, {
            'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/CM.Supervoid',
            'type': 'file',
            'name': 'CM.Supervoid'
        }, {
            'type': 'dir',
            'data': [{
                'type': 'dir',
                'data': [{
                    'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.forest',
                    'type': 'file',
                    'name': 'CM.forest'
                }, {
                    'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.benign',
                    'type': 'file',
                    'name': 'CM.benign'
                }, {
                    'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.dunes',
                    'type': 'file',
                    'name': 'CM.dunes'
                }],
                'name': 'CRUDE',
                'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE'
            }, {
                'type': 'dir',
                'data': [{
                    'type': 'dir',
                    'data': [{
                        'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.tangeant',
                        'type': 'file',
                        'name': 'CM.tangeant'
                    }, {
                        'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.astral',
                        'type': 'file',
                        'name': 'CM.astral'
                    }, {
                        'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.forking',
                        'type': 'file',
                        'name': 'CM.forking'
                    }],
                    'name': 'CRUDE',
                    'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE'
                }],
                'name': 'COMMODITIES',
                'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES'
            }],
            'name': 'DORAS',
            'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS'
        }],
        'name': 'MIPK',
        'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK'
    },
    '/generic_root/site_store': {
        'type': 'dir',
        'data': [{
            'type': 'dir',
            'data': [{
                'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/CM.toroidal',
                'type': 'file',
                'name': 'CM.toroidal'
            }, {
                'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/CM.Supervoid',
                'type': 'file',
                'name': 'CM.Supervoid'
            }, {
                'type': 'dir',
                'data': [{
                    'type': 'dir',
                    'data': [{
                        'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.forest',
                        'type': 'file',
                        'name': 'CM.forest'
                    }, {
                        'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.benign',
                        'type': 'file',
                        'name': 'CM.benign'
                    }, {
                        'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.dunes',
                        'type': 'file',
                        'name': 'CM.dunes'
                    }],
                    'name': 'CRUDE',
                    'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE'
                }, {
                    'type': 'dir',
                    'data': [{
                        'type': 'dir',
                        'data': [{
                            'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.tangeant',
                            'type': 'file',
                            'name': 'CM.tangeant'
                        }, {
                            'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.astral',
                            'type': 'file',
                            'name': 'CM.astral'
                        }, {
                            'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.forking',
                            'type': 'file',
                            'name': 'CM.forking'
                        }],
                        'name': 'CRUDE',
                        'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE'
                    }],
                    'name': 'COMMODITIES',
                    'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES'
                }],
                'name': 'DORAS',
                'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS'
            }],
            'name': 'MIPK',
            'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK'
        }],
        'name': 'site_store',
        'path': '/generic_root/site_store'
    },
    '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS': {
        'type': 'dir',
        'data': [{
            'type': 'dir',
            'data': [{
                'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.forest',
                'type': 'file',
                'name': 'CM.forest'
            }, {
                'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.benign',
                'type': 'file',
                'name': 'CM.benign'
            }, {
                'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.dunes',
                'type': 'file',
                'name': 'CM.dunes'
            }],
            'name': 'CRUDE',
            'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE'
        }, {
            'type': 'dir',
            'data': [{
                'type': 'dir',
                'data': [{
                    'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.tangeant',
                    'type': 'file',
                    'name': 'CM.tangeant'
                }, {
                    'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.astral',
                    'type': 'file',
                    'name': 'CM.astral'
                }, {
                    'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.forking',
                    'type': 'file',
                    'name': 'CM.forking'
                }],
                'name': 'CRUDE',
                'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE'
            }],
            'name': 'COMMODITIES',
            'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES'
        }],
        'name': 'DORAS',
        'path': '/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS'
    }
}
```

2 questions:

1. How to output the correct desired format? (example below)
2. Given above how can I optimize the function in time further for millions of list entries?

```
 desired output = {
    "type": "dir",
    "data": [{
        "type": "dir",
        "data": [{
            "path": "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/CM.toroidal",
            "type": "file",
            "name": "CM.toroidal"
        }, {
            "path": "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/CM.Supervoid",
            "type": "file",
            "name": "CM.Supervoid"
        }, {
            "type": "dir",
            "data": [{
                "type": "dir",
                "data": [{
                    "path": "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.forest",
                    "type": "file",
                    "name": "CM.forest"
                }, {
                    "path": "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.benign",
                    "type": "file",
                    "name": "CM.benign"
                }, {
                    "path": "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.dunes",
                    "type": "file",
                    "name": "CM.dunes"
                }],
                "name": "CRUDE",
                "path": "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE"
            }, {
                "type": "dir",
                "data": [{
                    "type": "dir",
                    "data": [{
                        "path": "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.tangeant",
                        "type": "file",
                        "name": "CM.tangeant"
                    }, {
                        "path": "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.astral",
                        "type": "file",
                        "name": "CM.astral"
                    }, {
                        "path": "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.forking",
                        "type": "file",
                        "name": "CM.forking"
                    }],
                    "name": "CRUDE",
                    "path": "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE"
                }],
                "name": "COMMODITIES",
                "path": "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES"
            }],
            "name": "DORAS",
            "path": "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS"
        }],
        "name": "MIPK",
        "path": "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK"
    }],
    "name": "site_store",
    "path": "/generic_root/site_store"
}
```

Comment: Can you specify what's the exact difference between the example output and the one you have?

Comment: `node_map` is a dict with keys of form `"/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE"` with several duplications. `desired_output` is a dict containing `"path"`, `"type"`, `"name"`, and `"data":[]` with no duplication of entries.  root_map will have `"/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES"` listed once undr it's own key and again under `"/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/"` and `"/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/"`

Comment: Did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015508/construct-a-tree-from-a-list-with-levels?rq=1 ?

Comment: Yes I've looked at this. Looks like the nesting is known beforehand however the loop looks simple i'll try to adapt it. Thank you. The structure is the problem as I'm not putting it under the "path" key but under "data" key on same level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with this solution that uses a navigator object to walk up and down the dict.

Firstly parsing the string, split from the path into the list of sub-directories.

Check if it exists at the current results level (items in the 'data' field with 'name' = blah handled by a lamdba), if not create it and move the navigator to this level.

Once the navigator has created or navigated to the correct sub-directory (last sub-directory in the parents list) then append a node object to the result array.

For the next path the navigator is reset to the full result and the process starts again.

Feedback welcome, I'm sure it could be improved.

```
def main():
    # Initialise
    root_path    = '/generic_root'
    store        = '/site_store'
    file_list    = [
        "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/CM.toroidal",
        "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/CM.Supervoid",
        "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.forest",
        "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.benign",
        "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/CRUDE/CM.dunes",
        "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.tangeant",
        "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.astral",
        "/generic_root/site_store/MIPK/DORAS/COMMODITIES/CRUDE/CM.forking"
    ]
    # Call loop and display results
    viewstore_tree_map = create_dir_tree(file_list, root_path, store)


def Node(full_path, name):
    '''
    full_path[STR] 
    name [STR]
    returns [DICT] node object
    '''
    return {
         'path': full_path,
         'name': name,
         'type': 'dir',
         'data': [],
    }

def Record(full_path):
    '''
    full_path[STR] 
    returns [DICT] record object
    '''
    return {
        'path': full_path,
        'name': full_path.rsplit('/', 1)[-1],
        'type': 'file',
    }

def joiner(delimiter, *args):
    '''
    delimiter[STR] 
    *args [STR]'s unpack sets and lists
    returns [STR] Joins path strings correctly
    '''
    return delimiter.join(list(args))


def create_dir_tree(file_list, root_path, store):
    '''
    file_list [LIST][STR]
    root_path [STR] - root directory
    store [STR] - store site (sub directory)
    returns [DICT] Nested dict of paths from a flat list
    '''
    #  Intiliase
    full_root = self.base_dir + store
    result = Node(full_root, store)
    for path in file_list):
        short_path = path.replace(full_root, '')
        # 1st pass: set navigator to result, 
        # Subsequent: Resets navigator object, and node_path for next path
        navigator = result
        node_path = full_root
        # Remove non-relevant parts of path
        parents = short_path.replace(str_filter, '').split('/')[1:-1]
        for parent in parents:
            node_path = joiner('/', node_path, parent)
            if not filter(lambda dir_rec: dir_rec['name'] == parent,
                          navigator['data']):
                # If node does not exist, append dir object to 'data'
                navigator['data'].append(Node(node_path, parent))
            # Move navigator to previously found node
            navigator = navigator['data'][-1]
        # Append record after constructing or navigating to correct path
        navigator['data'].append(Record(path))
    return result
```